# Can't log into Ubuntu 16.04. Upgrade from 14.04

Tags: 16.04, login

Total Nube here.  Upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, and won't login now upon restart.  I'm locked out of my PC now.  Help? Edit:  When I attempt to log in it just brings me back to the login screen.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean "won't login"? Is it a login loop, or will it just not accept your password?

Comment: I think its what you're calling a loop.  I type in my password.  It begins to do something as if its logging in.  Then it blinks, and returns me to my log in screen.  Doesn't matter what user.  The same.  If I type in my password incorrectly it says incorrect password. So its not my credentials...  Thoughts?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: none of that was helpful, in fact I'm worse off.  I screwed with the Nvidia and now the graphics look like crap.  BIG TEXT and Images

Comment: Can you log in? If no, Please enter the terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F2 (test different Fn keys if this doesn't pull up a black terminal screen). Type your username, press enter, type your password, press enter, then type these commands and paste the output into this question: `lspci | grep VGA`, and `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: OK.  I did that.  It pulled up a lot of data, buut I don't know what any of it means.

Comment: Please post the output into your question. Can you log in?

Comment: No I still cannot log in.  Is there a way to log in to the GUI from the terminal?

Comment: Please post the output of the commands.

Comment: I don't know how.  I'm writing you from a different PC

Comment: Can you take pictures and upload them? I really just need the model of your processor and graphics card. The output of the command should say something similar to AMD/Intel/nVidia (one or another) <model #>.

Answer (score 0):

@Someguy: You are probably getting logged in, but your graphical interface is failing almost immediately.  You keep saying you can't log in, but you can.  But your GUI doesn't keep  you logged in.  This happens because some package upgrades failed (did not include all required pieces) or because your user account has some bad settings that are no longer applicable.

The way to make sure you can log in was recommended by others. Get into the virtual terminal and make sure you can enter a password and that "it" works. There are ways to launch X11 from there, possibly as easy as typing "startx".  But that may not help if you have a failed graphical login going on.

Now, what is wrong with your graphical interface is the question?  Obviously the upgrade from 14 to 16 was too big  of a step and all of the packages are not working well together.

This diagnostic step sounds good to me. Get in the VT, log in, then create an entirely new user account.  Suppose you get logged in the VT as "joe", then you run "sudo adduser henry" to create a new account. THen run "sudo password henry" and type a password twice.  Then run "exit" to get out of the VT, go back to the VT where the GUI login is running. (I can't remember.  It used to be that was Alt-Ctl-F7, but I think it is on F1 in current Ubuntu).  Then try to log in as henry.  If you see success, it means accumulated settings in your user account, not the Ubuntu system are to blame for your trouble.

If the new account is a fail, it means the "upgrade" was a fail.  Frankly, I've been doing this 20 years and many upgrades fail, especially when you try to skip over several versions.  You are hopping over 15 entirely, and in my experience that can be bad.

Here is what I would do:

1. Get fresh media for Ubuntu 16.10 install. I'd install from scratch.  Question: how to save your home data content?  Hopefully, you have the HOME partition separate. Then it is easy.  Just don't let the installer do the automatic everything for you. Make  sure it does not reformat your HOME.

If the login fails like in the upgrade, then you have to go into the VT and start moving out some of the "dot" folders and files, configurations that are causing your trouble.

2. When are looking at the graphical  login, do you see any alternative desktops available.  I hate Ubuntu's Unity desktop, so I always have several others installed. It may be you already do  have one and if may be that alternative will allow you to log in and stay logged in.

I can't picture the login on Ubuntu right now. I know on Centos linux there is a little gear thing that appears after you put in your user name.  I think in Ubuntu there is a top right chooser thing where you can pick something besides Unity. Maybe you have Gnome or such.

The reason an alternative desktop might be OK is  that the one you were using is filled up with your personal settings  from version 14 and they are likely at the root of your trouble.

If that is not possible...

3. I have done this.  Log in on the VT and fix whatever is wrong. Check to see if your networking is alive (could run "apt update", for example).  This is a good chance to learn your way around the terminal and the package manager.  Then you start running "apt-get" commands to install/reinstall packages.

You might considering installing an entirely new desktop, such as my favorite XFCE4 desktop. If you install a fresh one, it is not going to be polluted by any duds hanging over from the old version.  There are many competing desktops, several can be installed as easily as "sudo apt-get install xfce4".

This may sound overwhelming to you if you are a Unix novice, but I promise that everybody who is going to survive in Linux will go through this once in a lifetime. At least. Let us know how it goes, but you need to be calm and take some breaths.  Don't think as though you are the only one to ever end up in this situation, we all have, and there are plenty of good ways around it.  I think the best is to reinstall, not upgrade.  My upgrades in Ubuntu were smooth from the various 14's to 15.10, but upgrade to 16.04 was a fail and I did a fresh install. Then the upgrade to 16.10 was not smooth and I ended up doing full reinstall.

Good luck, let us know how it goes.